# Why do we need to reshape (R,1) to (R,) for plotting?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot 3d plot.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot(xs,zs,targets)
ax.set_xlabel('xs')
ax.set_ylabel('zs')
ax.set_zlabel('Targets')
ax.view_init(azim=1000)
plt.show()
```

where shape of xs is (1000,1) and zs is (1000,1) and targets is (1000,1). But getting error as `input operand has more dimensions than allowed by the axis remapping.`

If we reshape targets as `targets = targets.reshape(1000,)` then plot works fine. Can anyone please explain?

Comment: Does `plot` docs say anything about the dimensions of its inputs?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.plot) says

> ```
> plot(self, xs, ys, *args, zdir='z', **kwargs)
>
> Plot 2D or 3D data.
>
> Parameters:   
> xs : 1D array-like
>      x coordinates of vertices.
>
> ys : 1D array-like
>      y coordinates of vertices.
>
> zs : scalar or 1D array-like
>      z coordinates of vertices; either one for all points or one for each point
> ```

Therefore, all inputs to the `plot` method of a 3D axes must be **one-dimensional**.

Comment: We have the xs as (1000,1) but targets as (1000,1) is not acceptable. Why dont we need to reshape xs and zs to (1000,) as well?

Comment: Because the function does not take 2D input.

Comment: I agree, but xs and zs has shape (1000,1) which is 2D why are they acceptable?

Comment: Because nobody cared about putting an error message in for that case.